# Elements stay not in Fieldset

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML Code

```
   <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <form>
            <fieldset class="fldset-class">
                <legend class="legend-class">Vorselektion</legend>

                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-3 kreisSpalten">
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="kreis shadow">
                                <span class="big counting">186</span><br /> <span
                                    class="secondText">Gesamt Bewerber</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="zweiterKreis shadow">
                                <span class="big2 counting">25</span><br /> <span
                                    class="secondText2">Verknüpft</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dritterKreis shadow">
                                <span class="big2 counting">6</span><br /> <span
                                    class="secondText2">Absage(n)</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
            </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

This gives me a circles which shloud sty inside the fieldset.
But it doesen't work.
The fieldset stays behind the circles. Here you can see what i mean:

[image]

And here is my CSS for each Circle for the first two:

```
.kreis {

text-align: center;
width: 110px;
height: 110px;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:white;
position:absolute;

border: 5px solid rgb(0, 122, 146);

-webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.zweiterKreis {

text-align: center;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:white;
position: absolute;
margin: 3% 50px 0 30%;
border: 5px solid rgb(106, 199, 44);

-webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}
```

So what must i do, that the circles stay inside the fieldset ?

Comment: Remove position absolute from .kreis & .zweiterKreis  and try

Comment: you are going totally wrong you can use simple  `display:flex`  `align-item:center`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with Position value to Relative.

```css
.kreis {

text-align: center;
width: 110px;
height: 110px;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:white;
position:absolute;

border: 5px solid rgb(0, 122, 146);

-webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}

.zweiterKreis {

text-align: center;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color:white;
position: relative;
margin: 3% 50px 0 30%;
border: 5px solid rgb(106, 199, 44);

-webkit-animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
animation: animation 1000ms linear both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <form>
            <fieldset class="fldset-class">
                <legend class="legend-class">Vorselektion</legend>

                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-3 kreisSpalten">
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="kreis shadow">
                                <span class="big counting">186</span><br /> <span
                                    class="secondText">Gesamt Bewerber</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="zweiterKreis shadow">
                                <span class="big2 counting">25</span><br /> <span
                                    class="secondText2">Verknüpft</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dritterKreis shadow">
                                <span class="big2 counting">6</span><br /> <span
                                    class="secondText2">Absage(n)</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
            </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```